# Spark Dataframes Multiple JOIN

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I want to add 2 columns LONG_IND and SHORT_IND to a JOIN between 2 Dataframes by comparing

1. First 3 letter Prefix values of ACCOUNT_NO Column from Dataframe 1 to be between Prefix_FROM and Prefix_TO Columns in Dataframe 2 (Number comparison)
2. Last 5 letter Suffix values of ACCOUNT_NO Column from Dataframe 1 to be between Suffix_FROM and Suffix_TO Columns in Dataframe 2 (Number comparison)
3. First 3 letter Prefix values of ACCOUNT_NO Column from Dataframe 1 to be between Prefix_FROM and Prefix_TO Columns in Dataframe 2 (Alphanumeric comparison)
4. Last 5 letter Suffix values of ACCOUNT_NO Column from Dataframe 1 to be between Suffix_FROM and Suffix_TO Columns in Dataframe 2 (Alphanumeric comparison)
5. Last 5 letter Suffix values of ACCOUNT_NO Column from Dataframe 1 to be ANYTHING (ALL in data) (Alphanumeric comparison)
6. ACCOUNT_NO Column from Dataframe 1 can be ANYTHING (ALL in data) (Default case)

   How to add for alphanumeric comparison and default cases in this same dataframe? If I write separate JOIN again, the LONG_IND ansd SHORT_IND columns

### Dataframe 1

---

```
ACCOUNT_NO,CostCenter,BU,MPU
0000001F,,BOXXBU          ,BOXXMP          
0000002Q,,BOXXBU          ,BOXXMP          
92115301,,BOXXBU          ,BOXXMP
32934789,,BOXXBU          ,BOXXMP
3FA34789,,BOXXBU          ,BOXXMP
3S534789,,BOXXBU          ,BOXXMP
```

### Dataframe 2

---

```
ACCT PFX FROM,ACCT PFX TO,ACCT SFX FROM,ACCT SFX TO,TIER 1 LONG,TIER 2 LONG,TIER 1 SHORT,TIER 2 SHORT
329,329,89276,89276,15,10,65,10
3FA,3FA,00001,00001,1,1,90,1
ALL,ALL,ALL,ALL,8,99,88,99
934,999,ALL,ALL,8,85,88,85
3S4,3S6,ALL,ALL,6,22,65,22
```

Now I have written the code below that works for numbers (**a and b from above**) shown as below using 2 options:

```
val getRuleDF = accDF.join(customerRulesDF,accDF("ACCOUNT_NO").substr(0, 3).between(customerRulesDF("ACCT_PFX_FROM"), customerRulesDF("ACCT_PFX_TO")) && accDF("ACCOUNT_NO").substr(4, 5).between(customerRulesDF("ACCT_SFX_FROM"), customerRulesDF("ACCT_SFX_TO")), "inner")
  .withColumn("LONG_IND", concatColumns(customerRulesDF("TIER_1_LONG"), customerRulesDF("TIER_2_LONG")) )
  .withColumn("SHORT_IND", concatColumns(customerRulesDF("TIER_1_SHORT"), customerRulesDF("TIER_2_SHORT")) )
```

OR

```
val getRule1DF = getRuleDF.join(customerRulesDF,
  (accDF("ACCOUNT_NO").substr(0, 3) >= customerRulesDF("ACCT_PFX_FROM")) &&
  (accDF("ACCOUNT_NO").substr(0, 3) <= customerRulesDF("ACCT_PFX_TO")) &&
  (accDF("ACCOUNT_NO").substr(4, 5) >= customerRulesDF("ACCT_SFX_FROM")) &&
  (accDF("ACCOUNT_NO").substr(4, 5) <=  customerRulesDF("ACCT_SFX_TO")), "inner")
  .withColumn("LONG_IND", concatColumns(customerRulesDF("TIER_1_LONG"), customerRulesDF("TIER_2_LONG")) )
  .withColumn("SHORT_IND", concatColumns(customerRulesDF("TIER_1_SHORT"), customerRulesDF("TIER_2_SHORT")) )
```

Comment: I am not sure if i got the question correctly. The conditions from `a` to `d` look like the joining conditions but conditions `e` and `f` look like the normal filters after the join. Can you be a little more specific on `Alphanumeric comparison` , `ANYTHING` and `Default case`.

Comment: This case --> 934,999,ALL,ALL,8,85,88,85
is when DATAFRAME1.ACCOUNT_NO Prefix should start anywhere between 934 and 999, but Suffix can be anything

The Default case is when DATAFRAME1.ACCOUNT_NO can have any prefix or any suffix, which is basically the Default case (specified by ALL in Dataframe 2 as below:
--> ALL,ALL,ALL,ALL,8,99,88,99

- LONG_IND is concatenation of TIER 1 LONG and TIER 2 LONG
- SHORT_IND is concatenation of TIER 1 SHORT and TIER 2 SHORT

Comment: Praveen thanks for your reply. 
Basically I have to add 2 columns LONG_IND and SHORT_IND based on the 
first 3 letters prefix of ACCOUNT_NO and last 5 letters suffix of ACCOUNT_NO from Dataframe 1 to be in the ranges of values given in Dataframe 2 
--> Prefix range of DATAFRAME1.ACCOUNT_NO should be between ACCT PFX FROM and ACCT PFX TO of DATAFRAME 2
--> Suffix range of DATAFRAME1.ACCOUNT_NO should be between ACCT SFX FROM and ACCT SFX TO of DATAFRAME 2